# PHP UTF-8 Security: Must I use mb_check_encoding() for Security Reasons on every Inputdata?

Tags: php, security, utf-8

Is `mb_check_encoding()` a must for secure PHP UTF-8 Apps?

Do I have to mandatorily use the function `mb_check_encoding()` on absolutely every input data, passed to a PHP UTF-8 Application to be "secure"?

**Whatare the reasons/attack vectors?**

Please give a short explain as to why this is important / what the attack vectors are. The mb_check_encoding() helps to protect against "Invalid Encoding Attack". But where in PHP could these become obvious/a security risk?

1.) If all data is outputted via `htmlspecialschars()` and I use prepared statements, is then the only remaining attack vector, that string comparisons might not match (comparing a valid with invalid UTF-8 for example in a security filter, where not matching might be problematic)? Or in the conrete example, would htmlspecialchars itself be vulnerable (if no correct UTF-8 is passend in) and would not encode the output, which of course would be a major security risk.

2.) Or are there worse complications comparable like buffer overflows, that allow directly hijacking the app?

3.) What further attack vectors/problems exist?

Comment: Any Reason for -1 Vote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Security: how can encoding be misused?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022369/php-security-how-can-encoding-be-misused)