# php - validate get cookie post data to ensure utf-8 encoding?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I am developing my first ever site that needs multilingual support so I've been researching how to get PHP/MySQL/Apache & browser to cooperate.  So far so good.

I've even got it so that it works against all checks I throw at it (from db, to db, php file encoding, apache adddefaultcharset, pdo connection string, php mb string functions, ini settings for different php versions, etc etc etc).

I had to add `accept-charset="utf-8"` to POST forms, though.  Though all browsers I tested did in fact match the charset of the page supplied, they also provide a tool for a user to manually select the character set.  While this is terrible for someone like me just learning i18n using utf8, I'm happy to report that **every browser I've tried has respected my accept-charset request**.

However, this made me think.. *what if a particular browser DIDN'T*?  Then there's GET vars and cookie vars.  What if another encoding got through somehow (better safe than sorry?)?

So, I have a question.  :)

- Would there be any reason to advise against a function like the following pseudo-code, *for just in case purposes*, and injecting it at the top of a global include?

  ```
  //mb_detect_encoding detects the utf-8 with everything I try to throw at it, so it seems reliable
  //in pseudo-code, a recursive calling function like so...
  foreach (get, post, cookie AS superglobal) {
       foreach (superglobal AS key => value) {
          //if array, call self recursively, otherwise parse value
          if (mb_detect_encoding(value) != 'utf-8') {
              unset(superglobal[key]);
          }
       }
  }
  ```

This way, as a last resort, if some other encoding made it through somehow, this function would take the data out.

I don't see the harm as this function won't see much action resulting from the check.  I could also attempt to `utf8_encode()` before throwing it away in the event that something did make it through.  Thoughts?  Can any bad come from this?  Am I being TOO paranoid?

I just want to be careful because I read character encoding attacks are possible.

EDIT:  I guess I could `array_map()` or `array_walk_recursive()` or something else. The implementation doesn't matter; the idea is important.

Comment: You do have the meta tag with UTF-8, yes?

Comment: I vote for "too paranoid".  How many _minutes_ would such a browser last?

Comment: I do have the meta tag, and php content type header.   My unicode setup is 100 percent working.   I read however that problems can arise if another encoding made its way through.   Not only data integrity but also unicode attacks.   I guess i should probably read up on that.   @rick james - custom browsers do exist by people who are looking to attack.

Comment: I would be interested to hear of "unicode attacks".

Comment: @rick - such as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022369/php-security-how-can-encoding-be-misused and I've read about something else it seems where an attacker would submit an invalid encoding in hopes the app didn't detect it (have to read more)